# Firestore (array-contains-any) query operator

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firestore. I am confused, what will be the output of this code.

```
collection ("products").where (
    "category" ,
    "array-contains-any" , ["Appliances" , "Electronics"]
)
```

You can simply write name of document. (Ex- document 1, document 3)
Document is shown in image.

[image: Products document image]

[For more information visit this page](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html?m=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple!
Let us consider this scenoario where you have all values as strings.
[image] 
**array-contains-any**

Parameter: (String, 'array-contains-any' , Array)

```
collection("products").where( "category" , "array-contains-any" , ["Appliances" , "Electronics"])
```

This would give us documents as the result which has `category` either `Appliances` or `Electronics` 
**Result:** [ 'Toaster', 'Baby Monitor', 'Blu-ray Player'] 
**array-contains**

Parameter: (String, 'array-contains' , String)

```
collection("products").where( "category" , "array-contains" , "Appliances")
```

This would give us documents as the result which has `category` with `Appliances`
**Result:** [ 'Toaster', 'Baby Monitor']

> So, this means that when you have multiple items to be searched, we
> can use **array-contains-any**, or else if you want to a single item
> to be present in a Array, then we can use **array-contains**

Answer (score 0):

The query will print any documents that have any of the values ["Appliances" , "Electronics"] in their `category` field.

So the query will retrieve documents:

- `Toaster` because it has an `Appliances` value in `category`.
- `Baby Monitor` because it has both `Appliances` and `Electronics` in `category`.
- `Blu-ray Player` because it has an `Electronics` value in `category`.

The query will **not** return `Lipstick` though, as that document has neither `Appliances` nor `Electronics` in its `category` field.